# How should I understand $\mathbf F^\mathbf n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to go through Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*. I am stuck in the first few pages because I can't wrap my head around fields.

The definition of $\mathbf F^\mathbf n$ was given as:
*the set of all lists of length $\mathbf n $ of elements of $\mathbf F$.*

okay, for simple cases such as $\mathbf n$ = 2 or 3, I think I understand it

$  \mathbf R^\mathbf 2 = \{(x_1, x_2): x_1, x_2 \in \mathbf R \} $ is basically any point on a plane, if **n** = 3, it's a point in a space and so on, but I can't understand expressions such as

1) $\mathbf R^{[0,1]}$
2) $\mathbf R^{\mathbf R}$

how should I understand these expressions?

1) seems to be any **R** between zero and one is that correct?
2) how is this different from plain **R**?

Comment: You can think of a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ as a function from $\{ 1,2,\ldots, n\}$ to $\mathbb R$.  This function takes $i$ as input and returns the real number $v_i$ as output.  This viewpoint suggests that instead of using the notation $\mathbb R^3$, perhaps we should instead use the notation $\mathbb R^{\{1,2,3\}}$ to emphasize that we are talking about the set of all functions from $\{1,2,3\}$ to $\mathbb R$.  We see from our new perspective that a function $v:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is kind of like a "vector" that has one component for each number in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 5):

$A^B$ where $B$ is a set means all **functions** from $B$ to $A$.  Your ${\bf R}^2$ corresponds to ${\bf R}^{\{1,2\}}$, i.e. a member $(x_1, x_2)$ of ${\bf R}^2$ corresponds to the function $f$ from $\{1,2\}$ to $\bf R$ with $f(1) = x_1$ and $f(2) = x_2$.  In the case of ${\bf R}^{[0,1]}$, your function $f$ goes from $[0,1]$ to $\bf R$, i.e. it has to specify a value $f(x)$ for every 
real number $x$ from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

if $A$ and $B$ are sets then the symbol $A^B$ is defined to mean the *set* of all functions with domain $B$ and image contained in $A$.

thus $R^{[0,1])}$ signifies the set of functions $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e the set of all real-valued functions on the closed unit interval.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure he defines what $S^T$ means when $S$ and $T$ are sets. This is the collection of all functions from $T$ to $S$.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this $A^B$ as the set of functions $f:B\longrightarrow A$. Each such function is a 'list of length $B$ of elements of $A$' in the sense that it associates to each element of $B$ an element of $A$. The function $f$ 'encodes' the list.